# Pandas dataframe - deltas of data with same ids

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
  type  unique_id  val
0    X          1   11
1    X          2   12
2    Y          1   20
3    Y          2   30
```

The desired output is

```
  type  unique_id  val delta
0    X          1   11 9
1    X          2   12 18
2    Y          1   20 0
3    Y          2   30 0
```

Namely, I want to match every `X` with the `Y` that has the same unique_id (the id is unique among the `X`s, and separately unique among the `Y`s). Then, I want to calculate the difference of `val` for each `X`, and its respective `Y` row. For the `Y`s, this value can be 0.

Comment: How does the data look after row 3? Does the same pattern continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the unique_id is in fact unique for the give type, you can group on it based on the data filtered for type `Y`.

```
gb = df[df.type == 'Y'].groupby('unique_id').first()
>>> gb
          type  val
unique_id          
1            Y   20
2            Y   30
```

You then join this to the original dataframe:

```
df = (df.set_index('unique_id')
        .join(gb, rsuffix='_'))
>>> df
          type  val type_  val_
unique_id                      
1            X   11     Y    20
1            Y   20     Y    20
2            X   12     Y    30
2            Y   30     Y    30
```

You can now calculate your delta:

```
df['delta'] = df.val_ - df.val
```

Finally, reshape the data back into your desired form:

```
df = (df.reset_index()
        .sort('type')
        .drop(['val_', 'type_'], axis='columns')

# Reorder columns.
>>> df[['type', 'unique_id', 'val', 'delta']]
  type  unique_id  val  delta
0    X          1   11      9
2    X          2   12     18
1    Y          1   20      0
3    Y          2   30      0
```